# Why Azure WebJob JobHost.CallAsync returns error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

Here is my code:

```
JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("Auth")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And in WebJob Run Details I see this information:

```
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: ERR ] 
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: ERR ] Parameter name: method
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(MethodInfo method, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: ERR ]    at XXX.Program.Main() in C:\XXX\Program.cs:line 286
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[04/16/2019 23:21:16 > 6b9633: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

I think I am using this method:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CallAsync(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, [System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = null])
```

Member of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost

Summary:
Calls a job method.

Parameters:

> method: The job method to call.
>   cancellationToken: The token to monitor for cancellation requests.

Returns:

> A System.Threading.Tasks.Task that will call the job method.

But looks like some override method is used.

My calling method has following signature:

```
private static async Task Auth()
```

How to call it corretly, avoiding errors?

Answer (score 2):

`GetMethod(string)` is to get public method, but you declared it as private so it returns null. Change the method to public should work.

PS: You can use `nameof` keyword to avoid using string literal to identify your method `typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Program.Auth))`

Comment: I changed Auth visibility to public, also I am using your approach to call. The error message is changed to: [ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task Auth()' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes? [04/17/2019 11:37:56 > 6b9633: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed [04/17/2019 11:37:56 > 6b9633: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Comment: I'm not really sure. Is your `Program` class also public?